# How to use findcontrol in createuserwizard1 complete step ...?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is this the right declaration of findcontrol for complete step of createuserwizard1 ?

Dim UserName As TextBox = CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Label11")

But when i use it its shows the error object expected !

What was the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the value of a Textbox to a generic control (especially one that is really a label). Plus you forgot the New keyword when initializing UserName.  Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may want to try the following...

```
'This will set the textbox's Text to the label's text.
Dim UserName As New Textbox 
UserName.Text = CType(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Label11"), Label).Text
```

Or

```
'This will cast the label to a new label control you define in code.
Dim UserName as New Label
UserName = CType(CreateUserWizard2.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Label11"), Label)
```